# Accessing variables inside embedded SWF?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm programming an AS3 application which loads an external SWF file to a movie clip in my stage. I need to read a variable inside the embedded SWF. I think I can, probably, do this through the `bgURL`, but I can't figure out how.

How can I read a variable inside the embedded SWF?

```
var bgLoader:Loader = new Loader();

var bgURL:URLRequest = new URLRequest("file.swf");
bgLoader.load(bgURL);
addChild(bgLoader);
```

Comment: Depends on where your variable is relative to file.swf. For example if there's a variable `myVar` at the top level of file.swf (think of it as global), you should be able to do something like: `trace(MovieClip(bgLoader.content).myVar);` **after the swf has completely loaded**

Comment: It's actually a few layers deep. If the loaded MovieClip was named "top", here how I'd access it:

trace(top._root.Player.played);

I don't quite understand what you did with the MovieClip, what does "MovieClip(obj).varName" mean?

Comment: is the external swf also AS3?

Comment: Just FYI: your question was [mentioned on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/337436/why-was-my-edit-rejected-and-improved) with regard to a rejected edit. That is the reason it is experiencing a bit more attention than would normally be the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be something like `trace(MovieClip(bgLoader.content).Player.played);`, but make sure you access the content in the Event.COMPLETE handler:

```
bgLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,bgLoaded);
function bgLoaded(event:Event):void{ trace(MovieClip(bgLoader.content).Player.played) }
```

bgLoader.content returns a DisplayObject, but you need to access you content as a MovieClip. To do so you use [casting](http://darronschall.com/weblog/2006/02/actionscript-3-casting.cfm).

This is presuming your external swf is also AS3 (good point Teo.sk !)
This bit: `_root.Player.played` looks like AS2. Unfortunately you can't access 
variables form a loaded AS2 movie directly. 
Still, you can use [Local Connection](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/LocalConnection.html) class to send variables back and forth betwen
AS2 and AS3. Luckily Grant Skinner wrote a nice little utility called [SWFBridge](http://gskinner.com/blog/archives/2007/07/swfbridge_easie.html)
to make this easier

Comment: I just found out the embedded swf is AS2. are you sure I can't access the variables? because, when I embedded the same swf in my C# Windows Application, I could access its variables.

Comment: I am pretty sure you can't access the as2 variables from an as3 swf which loads it. The as2 swf runs as an [AVM1Movie](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/AVM1Movie.html) instance in as3 which is restricted in order to run AVM1(as1 and 2 swfs) and AVM2(as3 swfs) side by side. I had no clue you can access variables from a C# Application, that's pretty cool.